# karate-gatling: how to simulate a karate feature except those scenarios tagged with @ignore

Tags: karate

I have a feature which defines a workflow for a gatling test. Gatling test is running, but how can I set a karate option to ignore scenarios that are tagged with `@ignore`?

Using a system property like `-Dkarate.options="--tags ~@ignore"` doesn't help:

```
mvn clean test-compile gatling:test -Dkarate.env=dev -Dkarate.options="--tags ~@ignore"
```

Maybe there is a way to provide something like `tags = "~@ignore"` to karate feature within a scala file?

```
val workflow = scenario("workflow").exec(karateFeature("classpath:performance/workflow.feature"))
```

What would be the correct way to do that?

Comment: can you help us test the fix as mentioned here: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/968#issuecomment-562816628

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great question - and we realize that we are missing this. Opened an issue: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/968